# how can i recover events which is removed by .off() method?

Tags: javascript

My code removes event handlers like this...

```
$('#div1').off("mouseover mouseleave");
```

but after this, I sometimes need to recover these events.

How can I recover these two events after that code?

Comment: You need to add them again, just like you originally did.  I'd recommend creating functions for setting and removing these things, if you expect to have to do it often.  Alternatively, put some logic in the handler functions to decided whether to run them or not, so you never have to remove the event handler mapping.

Comment: You need to re-add event handlers for those events. There's no way to "restore" the previous ones.

Comment: You can't, you have to rebind the event using `.on` like you probably did before the `.off` call.

Comment: Or do not unbind the events and put logic inside the event handlers to run or not.

Comment: Make the handlers reusable functions .i.e: `var handler1 = function(){...}` then `on('mouseover', handler1)` and if possibly also only detach the specific handler as well so you don't accidentally detach other events bound,..unless that's what you want. `off('mouseover', handler1)` You can also use namespacing if needed [**jQuery Off**](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: Thank you for advice i solved my problem!